# How can i convert from byte to bytearray in python?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, hex

How can I transform the output

> <class 'bytes'> b'6182398364795f8144054652414633...

to

> bytearray(b'a\x829\x83dy_\x81D\x05FRAF3_\x816\x05CHESB_m...

using python3?

Whole problem:

I need to read a *.DAT file into byte-format in python. I do this using this code

```
import binascii
fn = "abc.DAT"
with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
    hexdata = binascii.hexlify(f.read())
print(hexdata)
```

which gives me the result

> <class 'bytes'> b'6182398364795f8144054652414633...

I need to use the variable **hexdata** for postprocessing and I get an error because it is not in the right format. I know the format should look like the output of below code for **encoded_online**, where "encoded.txt" looks like

> 61823983 64795F81 44054652 4146335F 81360543 48455342 5F6D0531
> 36373935 7F6C1950 0E323032 31313230 38323332 3134355F 8167052B
> 30313030 7F816319 500E3230 32313132 30383233 32313138 5F816705
> 2B303130 307F6B19 500E3230

```
quote_h = open("encoded.txt", "r")
quote_h = quote_h.read()
encoded_online = bytearray.fromhex(quote_h)
print(type(encoded_online))
print(encoded_online)
```

which gives me

```
bytearray(b'a\x829\x83dy_\x81D\x05FRAF3_\x816\x05CHESB_m...
```

I know that this is basically the same as above output, as "a" maps to "61" in hex, "92 maps to "392, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using read without any argument reads the entire file, which causes the big byte-word. I think the easiest way for your usage would save the bytes into a list of bytes:

```
data = []
with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
    data.append(f.read(8))
```

Note that I used 8 bytes, because that's the length of the blocks you have given.

Now you can easily access your single byte-words. Of course, it would also work with the hexlify function, which makes it even easier:

```
data = []
with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
    data.append(binascii.hexlify(f.read(8)))
```

Comment: This gives the error "TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" for line "data.append(f.read(8))"

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong method by accident. I restructured my post by using lists instead.